# Weka machine learning:how to interprete Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, classification

I am using the explorer feature for classification. My .arff data file has 10 features of numeric and binary values; (only the ID of instances is nominal).I have abt 16 instances. The class to predict is Yes/No.i have used Naive bayes but i cantnot interpret the results,,does anyone know how to interpret results from naive Bayes classification?

Comment: There are many interpretations possible. Can you please be specific on what you want to get from the output (like what is my precision)?

Comment: actually I want to see the important features that lead to a decision making (YEs/No). But all that NB gives are probabilities, mean,stddv etc.. and moreover for all the features. that is my problem. i hope u understand me now... but, What information do the Precision and Recall give me abt the classification??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive Bayes doesn't select any important features. As you mentioned, the result of the training of a Naive Bayes classifier is the mean and variance for every feature. The classification of new samples into 'Yes' or 'No' is based on whether the values of features of the sample match best to the mean and variance of the trained features for either 'Yes' or 'No'.

You could use others algorithms to find the most informative attributes. In that case you might want to use a decision tree classifier, e.g. J48 in WEKA (which is the open-source implementation of [C4.5 decision tree algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm)). The first node in the resulting decision tree tells you which feature has the most predictive power.

Even better (as stated by Rushdi Shams in the other post); Weka's Explorer offers purpose build options to find the most useful attributes in a dataset. These options can be found under the `Select attributes` tab.

Comment: You are right. i just use the decision tree classifier in Weka and it has selected the important features for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As Sicco said NB cannot offer you the best features. Decision tree is a good choice because the branching can sometimes tell you the feature that is important- BUT NOT ALWAYS. In order to handle simple to complex featureset, you can use WEKA's SELECT ATTRIBUTE tab. There, you can find search methods and attribute evaluator. Depending on your task, you can choose the one that best suits you. They will provide you a ranking of the features (either from training data or from a k-fold cross validation). Personally, I believe that decision trees perform poor if your dataset is overfitting. In that case, a ranking of features is the standard way to select best features. Most of the times I use infogain and ranker algorithm. When you see your attributes are ranked from 1 to k, it is really nice to figure out the required features and unnecessary ones.