# Weka: How to get the probabilities of each class for the test instances

Tags: machine-learning, weka, classification

In the case of Weka's Explorer, is there any way to get the class probabilities of the test instances as classified by a Naive Bayes' classifier?

Comment: The standard output of Naive Bayes shows me the mean and standard deviation for each feature and for all classes. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite @Sicco. I would like to see the weights NB is assigning to the features. I know Weka explorer provides the mean and SD for each of the classes.  But it would be helpful if I can get the "weights", not the means/SD of a particular feature for any given class.

Comment: I can see your comment here. But I am not trying to get important features rather just trying to get the weights NB assigns to each feature (not the mean and SD of every feature for each class) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189953/weka-machine-learninghow-to-interprete-naive-bayes-classifier

Comment: I might be confused but I think NB doesn't assign any weights to the features. An instance is classified by selecting the class which has the most similar features as learned by the NB classifier. These features, in the case of NB, only consist of the mean of standard deviation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier).

Comment: So, in Layman's terms, by weights I meant the probability of the test instances http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/naive-bayes-classifier/ (sorry for using term weights, I understand it has different contexts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Weka Explorer on the `Classify` tab, click on `More options...` and tick `Output predictions`. Then `Start` the training and testing and the result shows you the probabilities of assigning each class for each test instance.

Comment: So, in probability distribution column for test instance 1 I havee {0.472 *0.528} and for test instance 2, I have {*1  0}. What does this column mean and how are the values in this column interpreted?

Comment: This means that test instance 1 had a probability of 0.472 to be assigned the first class and a probability of 0.528 to be assigned class 2. Class 2 has a higher probability so test instance 1 was assigned class 2. In test instance 2, the NB model predicted that it should be assigned to class 1 with a probability of 1.

Comment: @Sicco how such probabilities are computed?